# Open Google map with specific address in a browser

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, href

What is the url structure to search for an address in Google Maps?

I want to offer an address on my website that, when clicked, it will open google maps directly to an address from my script.

I want to create a link `<a href="..."></a>` which will open a Google Maps browser page that shows a map of a street address from my script.

Comment: Go to google maps, search your location, and click the share / link button, you will get the link you need.

Comment: but I want it dynamic , not just for that example

Comment: I think you can do `https://maps.google.com/maps?q=` with what you are looking for. So for example New York would be `https://maps.google.com/maps?q=New+York` and if it is more specific do something like `https://maps.google.com/maps?q=1st+avenue,New+York`

Comment: Documented here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You can do it like this:

this is your href: http://maps.google.com/?q=
everything that goes after q will be filled in the search filled and submitted, for example:
1200 Pennsylvania Ave SE, Washington, District of Columbia, 20003

So the link looks like this: `<a href="http://maps.google.com/?q=1200 Pennsylvania Ave SE, Washington, District of Columbia, 20003">...</a>`

If you need the "q" to be dynamic you can do it with simple jQuery code to update your href.

Comment: This might be too broad a question but it was exactly what I needed in a hurry. Saved me a lot of money. thank you.

Comment: can we display directions too by default when user open this url on google maps?

Comment: Yes, use this to generate directions from the current location to the given destination. This also works (at least on Android) to get the Maps app to go directly to the directions in the app.

`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=1200 Pennsylvania Ave SE, Washington, District of Columbia, 20003`

Answer (score 0):

Without showing a marker, you can jump to the location like this:

https://www.google.com/maps/@31.4719456,74.4173874