# Open google maps app on android at onClick event in react

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, google-maps

I created an react project that runs in an android webview. I extract different locations from my API.
A want when an marker it's clicked to open google maps app on android phone to go to that destination.
below is my react component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker
} from "react-google-maps";

const GmComponent = props => {
  useEffect(() => {
    function getData() {
      if (props.data.length === 0) {
        alert("nu exista nimic in apropiere de dumneavoastra");
      }
    }
    getData();
  }, [props.data]);
  const openGoogleMapss = (lat, lon) => {
    //open google maps for lat, lon coordinates
  };
  const markers = props.data.map(marker => {
    return (
      <Marker
        key={marker.id}
        position={{
          lat: parseFloat(marker.coordinates._lat),
          lng: parseFloat(marker.coordinates._long)
        }}
        icon={require("../assts/img.png")}
        onClick={() =>
          openGoogleMapss(marker.coordinates._lat, marker.coordinates._long)
        }
      />
    );
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={14}
        defaultCenter={{
          lat: parseFloat(props.locatie.lat),
          lng: parseFloat(props.locatie.lon)
        }}
      >
        {markers}
        <Marker
          position={{
            lat: parseFloat(props.locatie.lat),
            lng: parseFloat(props.locatie.lon)
          }}
        />
      </GoogleMap>
    </div>
  );
};
export default withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(GmComponent));
```

how to open google maps app from openGoogleMaps function?
sorry for my English :)
thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27419509/make-a-href-which-open-a-google-map-with-specific-address

Comment: ok but I want to search depending on latitude and longitude not dress

Comment: You can enter latitude and longitude also in the query, maps.google.com?q="latlong"